# sql - get the result of different ids from the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get some help from a sql query:

I have these 2 tables:

Table 1:

docs:

```
id<- unqiue key  |  docName  | userName
-----------------|-----------|-----------
 1               | document  | Me
 2               | testDoc   | Friend1
 3               | document  | Me`
```

and table 2:

history:

```
docId <-Unique Key | status | time of modification
-------------------|--------|---------------------
 1                 | Good   |  2008-08-08
 2                 | Bad    |  2012-05-17
 3                 | OK     |  2017-10-01
```

How can I make a query that for all `docName`s (same docName and userName from table `docs`), we get the latest stats?

This is the results I am looking for:

```
 docName | userName | status
---------|----------|-------- 
 document|  Me      | OK
 testDoc |  Friend1 | Bad
```

Maybe:

```
SELECT docs.docName, MAX(history.status), MAX(userName) 
from docs JOIN
     history
     ON docs.id = history.docId
GROUP by docs.docName;
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with teh database you are really using.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery.  In ANSI standard SQL, this would be:

```
select d.*,
       (select h.status
        from history h
        where h.docid = d.id
        order by h.modification_time desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as most_recent_status
from docs d;
```

In SQL Server, you would typically use `top 1` instead of the `fetch` clause.  In MySQL, you spell "fetch first 1 row only" as "limit 1".

Comment: Thanks. I used `select d.*,
       (select top 1 h.status
        from history h
        where h.docid = d.id
        order by h.modification_time desc
       ) as most_recent_status
from docs d;` but it still gives 2 entries instead of 1, for docName `document`. Should I use `Group By` in subquery?

Comment: @jsh6303 . . . You have duplicates docnames in in the document table.  You should probably figure out why.

Comment: That's the point. I was trying to get 'all docIds' for same documents from same users and get the latest status.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as per you sample output, you can use CTE, i.e:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT docName, 
         userName, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
              (PARTITION BY docName, userName 
               ORDER BY [time of modification] DESC) rn, 
         [status]
  FROM docs d
  JOIN history h on h.docId = d.id
  )
SELECT docName, userName, [status] 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

results:

```
docName    userName   status
---------- ---------- ----------
document   Me         OK
testDoc    Friend1    Bad
```